# Javascript: attempting to access variable outside of function getting 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the `time_pressed` variable outside of `function held()` by returning `time_pressed` and doing `console.log(held())` outside of the function. It is `console.log`-ing `undefined`. Why is it not working and how can I do what I need to do to access said variable outside of the function?

***Here is my code..***

```
function held(){
    var time_pressed;
    document.onmousedown = function(e){
        mousedown_time = getTime();
        console.log(mousedown_time);
    }
    document.onmouseup = function(e){
        time_pressed = getTime() - mousedown_time;
        console.log('You held your mouse down for', time_pressed,'miliseconds.');
    }
    return time_pressed
}
console.log(held())
```

Comment: It can't return from inside an event handler. If you need the variable outside then declare it outside the function and set it in the event handler. Even then, know that it will still be undefined until the time the event fires

Comment: Each function has it's own returned value.

Comment: `held` doesn't return anything, so `held()` doesn't resolve to a value.  A function has to *return something* in order for a value to be returned.

Comment: @aw04 editted my question per your instruction and I am still getting the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: @David editted my question per your instruction and I am still getting the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: You're still not thinking about the fact that what happens in the event handlers only happens when the event fires, you need to account for that. At the time your outer function returns, that value has not yet been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following function:

```
function held(){
    var time_pressed;
    return time_pressed;
}
console.log(held());
```

What do you expect the function to return?  No value has been defined, so the value is `undefined`.

The only thing(s) you're doing in that function is assigning event handler functions to the document.  Which means two things:

1. Those are separate functions and what *they* return isn't what *this* returns.
2. Those functions won't be executed until *some later time when that even occurs*.

You're successfully creating those event handlers.  So it's not clear *why* you're trying to log some returned value.  The function you're executing doesn't return anything, nor does it need to.  There's nothing to be logged.  Your *event handlers* will log to the console when *they* execute.

Answer (score 1):

So, `held()` just sets up the handlers in your code.  Your `time_pressed` variable holds nothing until the handlers fire to populate it.  Give this a try:

```
function held(){
    var time_pressed;
    var mousedown_time;
    document.onmousedown = function(e){
        mousedown_time = getTime();
        console.log(mousedown_time);
    }
    document.onmouseup = function(e){
        time_pressed = getTime() - mousedown_time;
        console.log('You held your mouse down for', time_pressed,'miliseconds.');
    }
}
held();
```

edit: for the sake of completeness, `getTime()` needs to be defined.  I went with:

```
function getTime(){ return new Date().getTime(); }
```

Comment: So this successfully console.logs the time, but I need the time returned outside of the function so I can use it in an if/else statement.

Comment: You'll need to call whatever function needs the time as part of the event handler, then.  You can't get what you need as a return statement because the events can fire at any point.  Perhaps restructure your question to include the usage of the value if my suggestion isn't clear.